# Erro docker laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ead'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I'm making some adjustments to a docker project with laravel but I'm having the following problem: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ead'**. Which is strange because I have the database created, every time I use the command: php artisan migrate I get this error. See my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

docker-compose.yml

```
mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7.22
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
       volumes:
           - ./.docker/mysql/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
       ports:
           - 3388:3306
         networks:
           - laravel-eti
```

I started using sail, but the problem continues. A new problem has arisen: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel_ead' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel_ead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')"

But there is the database when I access phpmyadmin, if I use the command: "docker exec -it laravel-api-ead-mysql-1 mysql -u root -p" and then SHOW DATABASE; my finger banks are:

> Database |
> +---------------------+ | information_schema | | mysql | | you_db | | performance_schema |

| sys
My banks within phpmyadmin do not appear

My mysql docker is not working:
[image]

I looked for help in some answers here but nothing helped

Comment: Maybe during `docker-compose up -d` the database or its location gets overwritten. Show your docker-compose.yml and maybe the Dockerfile for the `mysql` service

Comment: Can you share more details about your setup?

Comment: "My mysql docker is not working" - what does the log tell you about this?

Comment: I used "docker logs <my-container>" and got this problem: [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you a definitive answer without seeing your Docker configuration, but one recommendation is to make sure the `DB_HOST` value matches the name of the Docker service that contains your database.  For example if your `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
  app: # service name for php-fpm
    container_name: php-app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www

  database: # service name for database
    container_name: app-db
    image: mariadb:10.6.3
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

  web: # Nginx service name
    container_name: webserver-web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Then in my `.env` I would use `DB_HOST=database`. This is possible because Docker makes the service names of all related containers available as hostnames amongst each other.

One way to verify, assuming your Docker structure is similar, is you could start a bash shell against the service container that is running PHP and try to make a database connection directly.

```
cd some/path # root directory where your docker-compose.yml lives

docker-compose exec app /bin/bash

mysql --host=database --port=3306 -u root -proot
```

My suggestions are a shot in the dark, but hopefully something here will get you closer to finding your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I run mysql --host=database --port=3306 -u root -proot
I have:
bash: mysql: command not found

Comment: @Sapinn - Based on your updated example, the name of your database container is `mysql`. So try `mysql --host=mysql --port=3306 -u root -proot ` . This command will only work from the container that runs your laravel app. If you have the mysql client installed locally on your machine, you could also try `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3388 -u root -proot `

Comment: I'm getting a strange error: **mysql: [Warning] Using a password in the command line interface can be insecure. ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)**. I'm running inside the container, when I use the docker-compose exec app bash command and run mysql --host=mysql --port=3306 -u root -proot I have bash: mysql: command not found

Comment: @Sapinn is the name of the container that runs laravel called `app`? Based on the screenshot you posted in the description, I think it might be `laravel_8`. In that case the command you want is `docker-compose exec app laravel_8 bash` then within the container's shell run `mysql --host=mysql --port=3306 -u root -proot`. If you are using sail, the `laravel_8` container should have the MySQL client installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with the indentation of your volumes port and networks. and also I would recommend using a different mysql user. Also the DB_HOST and the db container name in the docker-compose file should be same and it should be explicitly defined as container_name in docker-compose file else the container name will be generated with your applicationname + service name. You could try modifying following things.

The .env file should be something like

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=my-db # this is the container name of the database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ead
DB_USERNAME=nonroot
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

and the docker-compose file

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7.22
  restart: unless-stopped
  container_name: ${DB_HOST} # This is the container name that should be used in .env
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  volumes:
    - ./.docker/mysql/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - 3388:3306
  networks:
    - laravel-eti
```